# `http.service` fail to start with `exit-code` or `protocol`

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-security2, oraclelinux

I'm configuring a new Apache web server on Oracle Linux 9 (comparable with RedHat/CentOS according to Oracle). The version of `httpd` is `2.4.51` and the version of `php` is `8.0.13`. However, the service failed to start with the following error (with `journalctl -xeu`:

```bash
httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I look up and many of similar error appear related to config file. But `apachectl configtest` returned `Syntax OK`, `httpd --help` give no output.

So I tried to comment out some config in `http.conf`, after commenting out the `mod-security` related line, it throws out new error message:

```bash
httpd.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
```

No other useful error message can be retrieved from `journalctl`.

Commenting out the `php` related lines also doesn't help. Besides, I found that to install `mod_security2` I have several other "module" to install, but I download this `mod_security2` from aap stream. To make sure the problem does not come from this module, I installed the required modules (except `libapr` and libapr-util`because error occurs on building, the`rpmbuild`cannot find`doxygen` even though I installed it) that are required in its documentation.

—————Update————

`error_log`:

```
[core:notice] [pid 4944:tid 4944] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[suexec:notice] - - AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)AH00016: Configuration Failed
[core:notice] [pid 4963:tid 4963] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[suexec:notice] - - AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[-:error] - - SecServerSignature: original signature too short. Please set ServerTokens to Full.
[-:notice] - - ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.3 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[:notice] [pid 4963:tid 4963] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.7.0"; loaded version="1.7.0"
[:notice] [pid 4963:tid 4963] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.44 "; loaded version="8.44 2020-02-12"
[:notice] [pid 4963:tid 4963] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.4"
[:notice] [pid 4963:tid 4963] ModSecurity: YAJL compiled version="2.1.0"
[:notice] [pid 4963:tid 4963] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.12"
[-:notice] - - ModSecurity: Original server signature: Apache
[:notice] [pid 4963:tid 4963] ModSecurity: Status engine is currently disabled, enable it by set SecStatusEngine to On.
[lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] - - AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[-:error] - - SecServerSignature: original signature too short. Please set ServerTokens to Full.
[core:notice] - - AH00094: Command line: 'httpd'
```

`AH00016` seem to be related with ssl cert, so I also attached the error log for ssl.

`ssl_error_log`:

```
[ssl:emerg] - - AH02562: Failed to configure certificate www.example.com:443:0 (with chain), check /etc/pki/tls/certs/example-wildcard.crt
[ssl:emerg] - - SSL Library Error: error:8000000D:system library::Permission denied (calling fopen(/etc/pki/tls/certs/example-wildcard.crt, r))
[ssl:emerg] - - SSL Library Error: error:10080002:BIO routines::system lib
[ssl:emerg] - - SSL Library Error: error:0A080002:SSL routines::system lib
```

I found a permission denied error to read my wildcard cert, and I noticed it was because I have the wrong ownership. I changed to what it should be, with a right of `644`.

BTW, `httpd -t` also returns `Syntax OK`.
Now that I rerun `httpd -t` with no root right returns error to file permission (solved by changing the ownership to `apache`):

```bash
# sudo -u apache httpd -t
AH00526: Syntax error on line 39 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf:
ModSecurity: Failed to open debug log file: /etc/httpd/logs/modsec_debug.log
```

Weird enough, when I check port listener I saw:

```bash
$ sudo netstat -punta | grep LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      4964/httpd          
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4964/httpd
```

`httpd` is listening when it failed to start?

Comment: Share `error log` from logs folder and `httpd -t` command output.

Comment: Error persist, even I changed `ServerTokens` to `full` as the log asked. @Pandurang

Comment: check mod_security.conf file(line 39) or share content in question

Comment: It has returned `Syntax OK` after I change the file ownership to `apache`. but the problem still exist (giving `The unit httpd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'protocol'.` in journal)

Comment: L39 is just defining the debug log file:`SecDebugLog /etc/httpd/logs/modsec_debug.log`

Comment: the latest output shows that apache is running.. Check the permission of modsec_debug.log

Comment: But `systemctl` tell me it is not running

Comment: share latest log in question or comment log line and test.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SELinux is denying access, probe this:

```
restorecon -vF /etc/pki/tls/certs/example-wildcard.crt
```